# How to ask PHP to find filename that contains something

Tags: php

im trying to do this :

```
$filename = "/destination/destination2/file_*";
```

" * " = anything

destination2 files :

file_somethingrandom

and since it $filename contains * so it should be selecting file_somethingrandom

how to do it?

Comment: so you want a random valid existing file chosen from a directory of files?

Comment: its not actually random, put im just giving an example, i want it to find filename where it contains something, if it was exist then ill ask it to die

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob) function like this:

```
$filename = "/destination/destination2/file_*";
foreach (glob($filename) as $filefound)
{
    echo "$filefound size " . filesize($filefound) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `$filefound` is not an array.  If you want an array, do this think: `$filesfound = glob($filename);`.  Then you will have an array called `$filesfound` with all the files that were found.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
foreach (glob("/destination/destination2/file_*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different functions other than echo, but it does what it does, randomly picks a filename in a group of files inside "/destination/destination2/" whose name contains "file_".

```
<?php

$filea = glob('/destination/destination2/file_*');

echo $filea[rand(0,count($filea)-1];

?>
```